# Clear IE browsing cache from externally

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I'm working on an ASP.NET app with Visual Studio.
The problem is that every time I launch the app, the IE has some css and js file cached so I have to manually clear the cache and only then run the app.

Added a external command in VS2012 that runs [this](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2011/03/21/quickly-clear-the-browser-cache-while-developing-client-side-apps-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) tutorial but it runs only once and then it does nothing (I didn't check what triggers this one time).

I'm looking for either VS configuration, external tool, command line, anything that will let me clear the cache by a single click without the need to open the IE.

Thanks

Comment: You could use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). Just open it, configure it to only clean the IE cache, and then just hit the clean files button every time you need to clear it. A better option to keep browsers from caching anything in the first place would be what @Andrew linked.

Comment: This post may help you.  It's not what you are asking, but this way you don't need to clear your cache each time you are running your program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file

Comment: This has been answered on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

Comment: Can you just press `Ctrl+F5` in IE?  That reloads the page and forces the files to be downloaded again.

Comment: On Chrome and FF you can use CTRL+SHIFT+R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a solution for my problem.
Don't know how I didn't see it before but the IE debugging window has a button for clearing the cache.

[image]

I couldn't find anything similar in Chrome (didn't look in FF and Safari) but for now I'm working only on IE so that's fine.

btw: I tried several other alternatives such as writing scripts/deleting registry entries but nothing worked. Some worked for the first time until next machine restart.
I hope someone can come up with a more efficient way.