# GWT caches app in browser? GWT app updates makes old app break

Tags: java, gwt

One of the biggest issue we have with GWT is that we release GWT app often that makes the GWT app in user browser break, that is, the app users get is the **old version** and if there are model changes especially the GWT app (that was cached breaks down)

One solution for this is to do a clear cache, however end-users really don't know about this. So we are looking for a way that our updates will force old GWT apps cached be replaced with the new version of the app.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: we provide a version number with each request. if the sended version number does not match the server version an old version is used and you can react with a message or something else...

Comment: How can we can that with GWT? What if we have released the app prior knowing about this, what is left for the users who's browser cached the old GWT app? Is there a work around for that?

Comment: Those clients does not support the version number and should get also a message.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: This has been covered in [the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching.) and [many](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422019/181497) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4819631/181497) here on SO. Have you tried any of those approaches?

Comment: @IgorKlimer Yes I can see in the docs http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html that there is this version number however my browser which used to open the old gwt version still not not download the new version I am using GWT 2.5.1

Comment: No, you are talking about a different thing (and different documentation pages) - IMHO, you should configure your webserver to set proper headers so that the browser doesn't cache the `*.nocache.*` files. I've had a similar discussion in a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28880280/181497).