# Scope of Cache-Control meta tag in HTML file

Tags: html, http, caching, meta, cache-control

When declaring

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">
```

inside the `head` tag of an HTML file which scope does this statement have?

Does it mean that all other files referenced in this document (like JavaScript or CSS files) shouldn't be cached either?

Or does it just refer to the current HTML file?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413283/3067148) it only affects the current HTML page. Is this true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent caching of my Javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The http-equiv attribute provides an HTTP header for the
>   information/value of the content attribute.
>
> The http-equiv attribute can be used to simulate an HTTP response
>   header.

see [HTML  http-equiv Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

[As mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file/7413283#7413283) this only seems to affect the current page.