# Jquery returns old value for an element on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an html as follows:

```
<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="20"/>
```

And there is a jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var currency_factor = $('#currency_factor').val()
     alert(currency_factor);
 }
```

Upon refresh the html line shows on the browser as:

```
<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="0"/>
```

But jquery returns 20.

Why is this happening?

Comment: after reload it returns 20?

Comment: Try `alert($('#currency_factor').val())` rather than use variable to save the value, does it work?

Comment: I have tried that, it returns the same value.

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser's cache ?

Comment: @guradio Yes, it alerts 20. But on the browser when I check it with inspect element, the value shows as 0.

Comment: It might be changed after `DOM` load. Place a `debugger` before `var currency_factor` and check the value of `$('#currency_factor').val()`

Comment: _"Upon refresh the html line shows on the browser as:

`<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="0"/>`
But jquery returns 20."_ The original `html` appears to have `value` set at `20` _"There is an html as follows:

`<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="20"/>`"_ What is expected result?

Comment: @rumman0786 Yes, when I run the code in incognito mode i.e when caching is disabled, it returns the correct value i.e 0. My question is how I can fix it with caching.

Comment: @Shruti What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 Upon reload I want the new value i.e 0 to be returned by the jquery but instead I the value is returned. On the basis, of the returned value some tasks have to be formed.

Comment: @Shruti Are you trying to set `value` of original `html` `<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="20"/>` to `0`, then at page reload set `value` to `0` ?, That is, the `value` that was set before page reload should be set after page reload?

Comment: @Shruti try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file) links

Comment: @guest271314 This is the  html snippet that gets populated on page load -   `<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="{{currency_factor}}"/>.`  The value of this input element is correctly set as 0 but jquery is returning the previous set value.

Comment: @Shruti What is value of `{{currency_factor}}` ? What do you mean by _"There is an html as follows:

`<input id="currency_factor" type="text" style="display:none;" value="20"/>`"_ ? Is `20` `value` set at original `html` ?  _"The value of this input element is correctly set as 0 but jquery is returning the previous set value."_ Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? Still not certain what expected result is? Do you expect dynamically set `value` of `input` element to retain the dynamically set `value` after page reload?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the header of your html file to disable caching:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
```

There are actually a number of cache control tags that may or may not be needed, depending on the browsers being used.  Here's another posting on StackOverflow that lists some of them: [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Actually, the snippet is a part of larger project . So I cannot disable caching for the entire page.

Comment: As your experiments show, the problem appears to be due to caching.  When you disable the cache or use the browser's debugging tools, you get the proper result.  If you can't disable caching, then perhaps you can use an XHR call (Web API) to retrieve the value and insert it into the page.  This will also allow you to update the one field (or however many fields you want) without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Try by first initializing it and then setting it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var currency_factor = 0;
     currency_factor = $('#currency_factor').val()
     alert(currency_factor);
 }
```

Comment: can you please try by refreshing the browser by pressing Ctrl +F5

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have more than one element with an `id` of `currency_factor`.  The first one's value will probably be returned.

Another possibility is that the value is changed after the `$(document).ready()` function has executed.  Try running `$('#currency_factor').val()` in the browser console after load.  If it returns `0` then it was changed *after* the page load.