# ScriptManagerProxy caches js files changes not reflected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager, asp.net-webcontrol

I use this to reference a file

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="script" runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/CommonResources/MapLocation.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Any changes i make to this script does not get reflected when i publish it the next time . Only when i clear the cache from the browser it shows how do i make the browser not cache this file ?

Comment: try adding version to your javascript file like Path="~/SomeFolder/SomeScript?v=0.0.1"

Comment: I cant do this everytime i change something i will need to change the path in the scriptmanager proxy.

Comment: hi check this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file#answer-7413243)