# create react app Configuration file after build app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I want a Config File (JSON) in root folder after build to config my app.

like `Translation` and `API Urls` and ...

Can I do this with create react app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create `config.js` or `json` file outside `src` directory and include it in `index.html` like

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

configure parameters in `config.js`

### config.js

```
var BASE_URL = "http://YOUR-URL";
```

you can get paramenters like

```
const BASE_URL = window.BASE_URL;
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that the `config.js` is not loaded fast enough? Especially in the built package (after running `npm run build)`.

E.g. if you have a file with content: `export const config = { baseUrl: window.BASE_URL }`

I think if you import that config afterwards (`import { config } from "..."`) then `config.baseUrl` could be `undefined`.

Comment: You have to import the `config.js` at the top of `index.html`. So the js files will load synchronously, it will load your bundle js only after `config.js`.

Comment: how you define separate files to be loaded according to the environment ?

Comment: Try some ways to generate the script `src` dynamically

Comment: How you would manage the versioning for this? I mean how you would force the client to use the latest version, not the cached version?

Comment: Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file

Comment: So, I should edit the index.html as well as the config file. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Is this solution secure?

Comment: Depends on your requirements

Comment: If I update the `config.js`, how can I make the webpage load it with the newest contents? The values do not update. I tried using query string as per link above but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can store you JSON file in the `public/` folder and it'll automatically provide this file when you host your Create React App.

Something like: `/public/my-configuration-file.json`

then when you restart your application:

`localhost:3000/my-configuration-file.json`

will provide you this json file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom hook that reads a "public" config file using fetch.

```
// This path is relative to root, e.g. http://localhost/config.json
const configFile = './config.json'

export function useConfig() {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(initialConfig);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function fetchConfig() {
            try {
                const response = await (await fetch(configFile)).json();
                setConfig(response);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }());
    }, []);

    return config;
}
```

Then use it anywhere in you app

```
function App() {

    const config = useConfig();

    return (
        <div>{config.foo}</div>
    );
}
```

You'll always have an up to date non-cached version of it's data.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can add your config parameters to the `.env` file with `REACT_APP_` prefix, and then read them in your code via `process.env`:

`.env` file:

```bash
# Create React App config:
PORT=8000
BROWSER=none

# Custom application config:
REACT_APP_CONFIG_PARAM=some_value
```

`App.tsx` file:

```
export const App = () => {
  return <div>config value is: {process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG_PARAM}</div>
}
```

And in your browser you'll see `config value is: some_value`

Comment: Thats a good idea for basic config, but i want a solution to config my app after build without rebuild. so the best way is using an json file in public folder