# JSON File Can't Be Fetched After Building React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app contains a Json file in which I am storing my configs.
The Json file is in my "public" directory.
Whenever i run `npm start` I am able to fetch the json file OK using the below code.

```
const appsettingsResponse = await fetch('appsettings.json');
const appsettings = await appsettingsResponse.json();
```

However, once i build the react app using `npm run build`
I am no longer able to access the json file even though it appears in the base directory of fhe "build" folder. In the console of my browser, it shows that the fetch request to `https://[ip]:[port]/appsettings.json` returns a 404 error.

How can I be able to access my settings file once my react app has been built? The intention here is to have a configuration file that I can easily access and change even after I have built the application. Then all I would have to do for my changes to pick is maybe restart my site.

Comment: Not sure why the fetch isnt working. But if you move your appsettings.json into the assets or a utils folder, you can simply import your configs without a fetch.

Comment: @Zxeenu I should probably clarify that my intention is to be able to easily change up configurations once my react app is built by just editing the appsettings.json file and maybe restarting my site. If I put it in assests, will I still be able to access it after I build my react app?

Comment: No, it would be bundled into the app build. I found this. Perhaps it might help - [Is it possible to serve Static files with create-react-app from public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014651/is-it-possible-to-serve-static-files-with-create-react-app-from-public-folder)

Comment: @Zxeenu I ended up using this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369477/create-react-app-configuration-file-after-build-app . For whatever reason, loading a json file from the base directory of "build" is not possible. Using a javascript file or txt file on the other hand works.