# Force HTML reload cache file

Tags: html, browser-cache

With JS and CSS, I've forced the reload for the new files with href="styles.css?v=1" and script src="scripts.js?v=1" in my code, but where / what do I write for it to force the reload of my HTML page? I've made changes but it's not picking them up unless I manually refresh/clear the cache, which is okay in my case but I can't control it when other people are looking at the my site.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

There 2 common approaches:

1. set a meta no cache:
2. Or set up your web server to add cache control policy

Answer (score 0):

The link below the question is to a 10-year-old answer. I tried this, and it *does not* prevent Firefox using its cached page, ignoring updates on the server. I can't set up the server either – it's a free hosted site where I am trialling the work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Instructions on how to clear my own browser cache are well posted but irrelevant: I can't tell readers to clear their browser cache and it's a very blunt tool anyway – other pages will have their cache removed too.

But what does work very nicely is to rename my page from

```
index.html
```

to

```
index.php
```

It doesn't even contain any PHP code directly, although it does link to files that do.

However I am still wondering how the media solves the problem of making sure readers have up-to-date news.