# How do I add a Unix timestamp for a script src string on a static HTML webpage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've come up with this, but it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/test.php?nocache=" + Date.now() + "></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It has to be part of the `src` string. I believe I could do `<script> console.log(Date.now()); </script>` if all I wanted to do was to output the Unix timestamp in the browser console, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to prevent the `/test.php` (which handles logging of page loads) from being cached by browsers, and since the page itself is not being served dynamically, I have to do it client-side.

Comment: `<script> var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = '/test.php?nocache=' + Date.now(); document.head.appendChild(s); </script>`

Comment: Just send a no-cache header from the php script?! No need to do that by dynamically loading scripts with a cache-busting URI parameter.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute js in HTML attribute. But you could do like this

```
<script>
const script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='/test.php?nocache=' + Date.now();
document.head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load your script after the page has loaded. This way you can dynamically set your script's `src` attribute:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src","/test.php?nocache=" + Date.now());
document.body.appendChild(script);
```